# Telling "other" Tasks to pause in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Start() 
{
   var numDrivers = 2;
   List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
   var motherDriver = GetMotherDriver();
   while (numDrivers != 0) 
   {
       var rnd = new Random();
       var r = rnd.Next(itemArray.Count);

       var target = itemArray[r];
       var proxyDriver = GetProxiedDriver();

       tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => HandleIntro(proxyDriver)));
       numDrivers--;
   }

   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

This is working, but every once in a while, `HandleIntro` comes across an error that requires `motherDriver`to be reset.  Usually if one of the `proxyDriver`s hits this case, all of them will immediately.  I need to prevent the `motherDriver` from being respawned multiple times, so I try to manage this with a boolean `isPaused` and `while` loops. From within `HandleIntro`, I try to use a global variable that the first Task sets to tell the others to pause until it's done:

```
 private bool _isPaused;

 private async Task Start(){ 
   _isPaused = false;
   //code
 }

 private async Task HandleIntro(Driver driver) {
       // wait for isPaused to get set to false
       while(_isPaused){}
       // do stuff
       if(errorOccurs){
           FixProblem();
       }
 }

 private void FixProblem(){
         if (!_isPaused){
             _isPaused = true;
             // spawn new motherDriver
             _isPaused = false;
         } else{
             // hold here until other thread sets isPaused = false
             while (_isPaused){}
          }  
 }
```

But the compiler is telling me that the `while (_isPaused)` in `FixProblem` is always `true` - as if it doesn't see that the value will be set by another thread at some point.  This tells me that I'm going about this the wrong way.  Is this the correct approach?  How can this be handled properly?

Comment: Your code is either incomplete or there is a typo: Sometimes you use `_isPaused`, and sometimes `isPaused `.

Comment: `HandleIntro(proxyDriver, target)` method is not included - the same only takes one parameter.

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus - it's a typo.  I tried to simplify the code so excuse any small inconsistencies

Comment: @Kami it's a typo.  I tried to simplify the code so excuse any small inconsistencies

Comment: Just as a side note - you are aware that calling `var rnd = new Random();` within a loop can cause the same seed to be used so your call `var r = rnd.Next(itemArray.Count);` can then produce the same value? You really need to instantiate `rnd` once at the class-level.

Comment: @Enigmativity - noted, and taken care of.  Thanks for that.

Comment: Where do you use `motherDriver`? Do you pass a reference to it inside the tasks or in `HandleInfo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sharing the `_isPaused` variable across the various tasks.  As such, when one task alters the value of the variable; all threads enter the new `motherDriver` initialisation process.

You need to synchronise access to the restart `motherDriver` control block to ensure only one thread can restart the process.  Try something like :

```
private static object objectlock = new object();

private void FixProblem(){
   lock(objectlock)
   {
      if (!_isPaused && motherDriverNeedsTobeRestarted){
         _isPaused = true;
         // spawn new motherDriver
         _isPaused = false;
      }
   }
}
```

This will ensure that in the event of a problem the `motherDriver` is restarted before the tasks shutdown.

Comment: Thanks.  What happens when the other tasks try to access FixProblem?  I need them to stay alive until FixProblem completes.

Comment: @RobVious First thread to reach the lock statement will block all others until it is completed - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx.  I have added a check for `motherDriverNeedsToBeRestarted` into the sample code - This would be a method or something similar that checks if the `motherDriver` needs to be restarted to prevent duplicate restarts.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `volatile` keyword to the `_isPaused` field may solve the issue, but I would recommend using proper synchronization with a `lock`.